# Есть ли возможность скрывать куски страниц сайта в мобильной версии не используя CSS?

Tags: html, адаптивная-верстка

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли аналог кода

```
<picture>
<source media="(max-width: 799px)" 
srcset="/upload/img1.jpg" width="100%" height="auto"> 
<source media="(min-width: 800px)" 
srcset="/upload/img2.jpg" width="100%" height="auto"> 
<img width="100%" height="auto"
src="/upload/img.jpg"> 
</picture>
```

но не для картинок, а для текста? В CSS-файл залезть не могу, пытаюсь найти варианты верстки чистым html.

Comment: только на html - нет.

Comment: То есть подмена картинки чистым html возможна, а подмена текста - нет? неуниверсальненько как-то( с другой стороны - это доказывает что моя проблема не в неумении пользоваться гуглом

Comment: Подмены картинки нет. Есть элемент, который можно использовать для выбора правильного разрешения картинки. У текста нет разрешения - соответственно и специальный элемент не нужен. Стили задаются в css - там и стоит менять. Ну и всегда можно удалить текст с помощью `js`